# I can't use `\width` as the argument for `\parbox` or `minipage`

Tags: minipage, width, dimensions, parbox

I can't use `\width` as the argument for `\parbox` or `minipage`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Bla \begin{minipage}{\width}{test}\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

To my understanding, everything I've read says that this should work (for instance [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#parbox,_minipage,_and_pbox) and [minipage](/questions/tagged/minipage) tag wiki).

Why is this not working?

Comment: `\width` is no regular macro

Comment: It should not work, but you do not say what you want it to do, perhaps you are looking for `\textwidth` ? Also you do not need the `{}` around `test`

Comment: According to what I've read, this should be a way to let `minipage` or `\parbox` have the natural width of the content (in this case "test".)

Comment: eek that wikibook page is wrong in so many places.

Comment: My end goal is to give `minipage` a width equal to "remaining \linewidth".

Comment: Box commands such as `\makebox` and \resizebox` allow `\width` in that sense but it would make no sense for parbox, barbox breaks the content into lines of the specified width, so teh width needs to be known in advance, there is no "natural width"

Comment: that goal does not match the way tex works: all boxes and macros in a paragraph are resolved first, then the entire paragraph is subjected to a least cost algorithm to decide where to add linebreaks, so "remaining `\linewidth`" is not something that is defined at the point that the parbox is set. If you gave an example of your actual use case, someone could suggest some code.

Comment: That makes sense. I only thought that it would work because I read it in so many places (including TSE).

Comment: If you can find anywhere on this site that suggests that `\width` works in `\parbox` add a link here and I will fix the page

Comment: The tag wiki [tag:minipage]. Or am I misreading?

Comment: @gebruiker: True, the tag wiki says `\width`, etc. but that is wrong. Actually the arguments are meant, not length macros. I'll change the tag info. The `\width` etc. macros are used inside of a group and are not visible outside.

Comment: @gebruiker The last paragraph in the tag description was incorrect; I removed it. Note that `<width>` refers to an explicit width, not to `\width` that can only be used with `\makebox`, `\framebox` `\raisebox` and some other places, not with `minipage` or `\parbox`. In the admissible case, the box can be typeset and its natural width measured; this is not possible with `minipage` or `\parbox`, which typeset their contents with the width set by the mandatory `<width>` argument.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your comments on the mistakes in the Wikibook and "the way TeX works" I found very useful. Could you post them as an answer? Then I will accept.

Comment: BTW, In my actual use case, `\linewidth` -15em will suffice, as far as I can tell now. I think I'll manage to do that, but thanks for the offer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\width` is a command which is only locally defined in boxes that have a natural width, so

```
\makebox[2\width]{test}
```

makes a box twice as wide as would normally be the case.

However the content of a  `\parbox` or `minipage` has no natural width in that sense, it is set in vertical mode so broken into lines to a width that must be specified in advance.

Answer (score 5):

A variable minipage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
    Bla \fbox{\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}% maximal of linewidth
        foo\\bar\\baz
    \end{varwidth}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this particular case not quite what I want. But I can see this being useful other times, so +1 nontheless.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the `eqparbox` package might be of interest to you: it defines commands `\eqparbox`, `\eqmakebox`, `\eqframebox` , a length `\eqboxwidth` and the `eqminipage` environment, which use a tag, so that all boxes which share the same tag have the width of the widest box with this tag. Here is a demo:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

        \fbox{\eqparbox{boxa}{Blahblahblah, blahblahblah, blahblahblah…}}
        \bigskip

        \eqframebox[boxa]{Blahblahblahblah}
        \bigskip

        \eqframebox[boxa]{Blahblahblah, blahblahblah, blahblahblah…}
        \bigskip

        \fbox{\parbox{\eqboxwidth{boxa}}{\lipsum[2]}}

\end{document}
```

[image]